# Add query param at runtime when using CXF proxy client

Tags: jax-rs, cxfrs

So I'm using CXF-RS proxy feature to create reusable REST client that I will use in multiple applications. So I have an interface, something like that :

```
@Path("/hello")
public interface HelloService {

    @GET
    @Path("sayHello")
    String sayHello(@QueryParam("name") String name);
}
```

And I'm creating the client with :

```
JAXRSClientFactory.create(address, HelloService.class, Collections.singletonList(JacksonJsonProvider.class), true)
```

But now I need depending on the configuration of the application to send an additional query parameter to the request. I would like not to change the interface HelloService and instead use some kind of filter to handle this. I saw the `ClientRequestFilter` but I don't know if it's the right tool and how I should add it to the proxy (all the tutorials I saw use `ClientBuilder.newClient()` and not a proxy).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use a `ClientRequestFilter` for this. Say you wanted to add a query param. You could do something like

```
public class MyClientFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        request.setUri(UriBuilder.fromUri(request.getUri())
                .queryParam("foo", "bar")
                .build());
    }
}
```

To register it, you just add it to the list you pass as the third argument to `JAXRSClientFactory.create`. Look at the docs for [`JAXRSClientFactory`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/JAXRSClientFactory.html). You can see the overloaded `create` methods that accepts a list of providers. The `ClientRequestFilter` is a kind of provider.

Comment: There is a bug where if I provide the ClientRequestFilter as a lambda it doesn't work, but with an anonymous class it does work. Thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot.